# How do I debug ruby-ldap when a method only returns false?

Tags: ruby, active-directory, ruby-1.9, netldap

My goal is to move an account to another OU. My understanding is that the following code should do the job. However, it returns `false`. There is no error, warning or exceptions. How do I debug why this isn't working?

```
secure_ldap.rename(
    olddn: self.dn, 
    newrdn: "CN=#{self.cn}", 
    delete_attributes: true, 
    new_superior: "#{ou}"
  )
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, one approach might be to add [pry](https://github.com/pry/pry) and [pry-byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug) to your application. Modify your code to include `binding.pry` then run your application:

```
Frame number: 0/0

From: ./test.rb @ line 1 :

 => 1: binding.pry
    2: secure_ldap.rename(
    3:   olddn: self.dn,
    4:   newrdn: "CN=#{self.cn}",
    5:   delete_attributes: true,
    6:   new_superior: "#{ou}"

=>
```

Now use [`step`](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/pry-byebug#commands) to step through the execution line by line. It will allow you to step into the [`rename` method](https://github.com/ruby-ldap/ruby-net-ldap/blob/9daa954061c2a071345bd18d462db5af8acfe8a0/lib/net/ldap/connection.rb#L649-L667) call inside of net-ldap, and for example inspect the local variables within that method call.

Comment: `step` here would raise the same error the OP got in the first place. What he really needs is the specs on LDAP itself and proper strings to pass to it's commands.

Comment: @lacostenycoder He specifically asked “How do I debug why this isn't working?” I explained a technique for debugging. He didn’t ask “Why isn’t this working?”

Answer (score 0):

The error is not a ruby error.  When dealing with ruby standard lib interfaces to system programs such as LDAP, refer to it's own documentation source.

In your case you're probably looking for https://ldap.com/ldap-dns-and-rdns/ which explains strings to use and which ones need to be escaped.